# Unity3D application won't start properly via Task Scheduler or Services

Tags: windows, boot, task-scheduler, unity3d

I've been trying to get an application made with the Unity3D game engine to start on Windows boot. Currently, I've put a shortcut in the Startup folder but this requires a user to log on to the system. I'm looking for a way to start my Unity application without user interaction.

I've tried adding the .exe as a service and as a task in the Task Scheduler. I noticed that both these methods manage to start a process, visible in the Task Manager. See the following links:

[image: http://imgur.com/Gjw4yuV,0cQvuJq#0]

[image: http://imgur.com/Gjw4yuV,0cQvuJq#1]

Running the exe is supposed to launch a window, but this doesn't happen when launched via Task Scheduler/Services. I assume this is because something gets suppressed when run this way, but what?

I've tried running a batch script via Task Scheduler, which then start the EXE, but that gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Unity3D is unable to acquire a graphics device when run as a background process. This means that running a Unity3D application that requires graphics as a background process cannot work. However, non-graphics applications started with the -batchmode command via Task Scheduler can work.